# I lost the track of my screenshots folder while trying a batch command and I don't know where to look for my screen-shots

Tags: windows-8.1, batch, windows-registry, screenshot

I regularly take Screenshots using the  Win + PrtScr .
My work involved frequent changing of Screen-shot folder, so instead of going to Folder-properties and Moving Location everytime, I decided to automate it using a batch code something like this:

```
mklink /D C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\Screenshots "E:\example\"
```

Now something wierd happened, and the screenshots I was taking were neither in old folder nor in the new one. And I can't see any options to (Move) in both folders' properties.
What do I do?

Is the folder location stored in Windows Registry?

P.S : I use Windows 8.1 .

Comment: Use Windows Search.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No it doesn't work